# Wordpress backup(on another server)leading to old server addy and WP

Tags: server, backup

So long story short, someone told me about BACKUPBUDDY and how good it is, etc,
and it is...now long story short, one of my clients, wants to move their site from FATCOW to HOSTGATOR.

I went in, created the backup with BACKUPBUDDY on the old site(fat cow), then went to the new site and migrated the info.(into hostgator)

now obviously for testing and other edits they want made,etc i log into the server or view the new site on the browser with their IP address.(host gator the new one)...and i havent pointed the domains to new site yet....

now that said, i noticed that when i use for example, "ip address / wp-login.php"
it logs me in but then when i look up in the address bar, it says the FATCOW(old server) name/domain instead of the IP.

so instead of seeing "ip addy /wplogin " i see " full name of site/wp-login "

So my quesiton is , whats happening? if i cant fix this, i cant really test to make sure all is okay b4 pointing the nameservers.

Any ideas as to whats going on? im a bit of a WP noob so...

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database still has the domain as the URL to use so it will always redirect you to the old server.

The best solution is to change your `hosts` file.

```
123.456.789.0     yourdomain.com
```

By using the NEW IP address you are forcing your computer to use the new server when going to `yourdomain.com`. That way you can login and do everything, making sure all is perfect before switching DNS.

Comment: but i coulda swore that backup buddy auto changed all that when migrating?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how their migrations work, but even still changing your hosts file is the best way to test your site using its real domain while keeping it private.

Comment: hmm ok, so let me ask you this. as far as "change my hosts file" how would i do that? only hosts file i know of is windows hosts files lol...im sure thats noot it lol. Thanks

Comment: That's EXACTLY it. Probably at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Hey Developdaly, ok so what exactly am i looking for? my addy i use with wamp is 127.0.0.1 and there are a bunch of entries in there...what is it i want to change? thanks in advanced

Comment: Don't change anything, just add a line in the format as my original answer using the IP of your new server. It will help to flush the DNS also, or you'll just have to refresh the page a bunch of times.